# Do not allow duplicate link to be removed through edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should users be allowed to remove the “Possible Duplicate” links on closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/should-users-be-allowed-to-remove-the-possible-duplicate-links-on-closed-quest)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733675/operator-in-c-sharp) was closed as an exact duplicate. As such, Community edited it and added the "Exact Duplicate" link. Seven minutes later, a suggested edit was approved, and this suggested edit was presumably on the original post that did not have the "Exact Duplicate" link, so it got removed.

Is there some way to prevent the "Exact Duplicate" link from being removed by edits? I think the only way that it could be removed with nobody knowing is through the suggested edit mechanism, but I'm not entirely sure about that...

Comment: The duplicate links functionality was added as a convenience... They are just an ordinary edit; they don't have any preferential treatment over other edits, other than mods occasionally restoring the links, as Anna Lear did on the linked question.  In practice, this is rarely a problem.

Comment: Better yet, if re-opened that section may not get removed properly if it's been changed from the auto-inserted version.  I believe the dev stance is `status-notimportantenoughtochangerightnow` which is OK with me.  :P

Comment: @Robert: This functionality also allows users to retract their up or down vote from a question upon closing because it has been "edited." I wouldn't consider adding that box to the top of the post to be a true edit that would merit the retraction of your vote after the grace period.